# Get Unknown Post Variable

Tags: php, post

Normally I know how to get `POST`ed variable. I know how to get known post. Its `$_POST['knownpost'];`. But now, I'm sending `POST` by `for` method. Let me explain.

I explained on my code

```
    for($i=1;$i<=count($iniVersions);$i++){
    echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\">";
    echo $versionString;
    echo "<div align=\"right\"><form method=\"post\" ><button class=\"btn btn-warning\" type=\"submit\" name=\"".$i."\">"; //look my post name is unknown. Its a variable.
    echo "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button></form></div>";
    echo "</li>";
    }
```

So how can I get `POST` after `POST` action?

Comment: A number of ways - the obvious one is to keep the name consistent and change the value: `<button type=\"submit\" name=\"version\" value=\"".$i."\">` then `echo $_POST['version'];`

Comment: `$i` is a number better try `name=\"knownpost[".$i."]\"` and `$_POST['knownpost'][1]` or just `knownpost[]`

Comment: And foreach a form? Why then not give fixed name allways? You only have to  add a hidden value like @Kervon Ryan says

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to go about this. The first thing is I wouldn't reccommend doing that. You can add a hidden element with one name and add a value to that element and use the value instead. Code below.

```
for($i=1;$i<=count($iniVersions);$i++){
echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\">";
echo $versionString;
echo "<div align=\"right\"><form method=\"post\" ><input type='hidden' name='whatever' value='".$i."' /><button class=\"btn btn-warning\" type=\"submit\" name=\"".$i."\">"; //look my post name is unknown. Its a variable.
echo "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button></form></div>";
echo "</li>";
}
```

Or you can change the form action to `action='action.php?nameToGet=". $i ."'` and use a get method to get the value but I don't recommend this as it defeats the purpose of the POST.